# instant segmentation fault with debian and std::thread c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, debian, stdthread

got this problem - in title..

I have this code:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

void my_thread_func()
{
    std::cout<<"hello"<<std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t(my_thread_func);
    t.join();
}
```

taken somewhere from web. compiler options -pthread -std=gnu++0x
(also tried -std=c++0x) and I have segfault. All is on Debian on vmBox.. I have launched other codes before, and they worked. Suddenly I have segfault on threads with std::thread in all working apps.

EDIT: this is from gdb:

```
(gdb) where
#0  0x00000000 in ?? ()
#1  0x08048dc9 in thread<void (*)()> (this=0xbffff3fc, 
    __f=0x8048b9f <my_thread_func()>) at /usr/include/c++/4.4/thread:129
#2  0x08048bea in main () at ../test.cpp:18
```

(when I launch more advanced apps with std::thread t(&ClassName::my_thread_func,ptr) error is same, but other line [thread:133])

I was searching trough the web but I have not found nothing suitable.

Comment: Works with boost::thread? What version of gcc? And how about look at /usr/include/c++/4.4/thread:129?

Comment: I tried it on Ubuntu 11.04 and it works fine for me. No segfault.

Comment: g++ (Debian 4.4.5-8) 4.4.5 , didn't check with boost

Comment: Do you get a "Pure virtual function called" message?

Comment: nope.. besides.. I do not want to use boost ..

Comment: @Wiciu actual version is 4.7. About your version check http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.4/cxx0x_status.html

Comment: yeah.. but I am pretty weak in linux stuff. and apt-get shows me that I have newest v. for debian.. I will try to update all

Answer (score 7):

compile with `g++ -std=c++0x -lpthread`. Note the `l` before `pthread`.

Answer (score 1):

Gcc 4.4 support for C++11 features is extremely limited, especially in the threading area. I have seen lots of thread related crashes in gcc 4.4 and 4.5 due to the library not being ready.

I am pretty confident that it is a compiler "bug"* and suggest that you upgrade to at least gcc 4.7.

*"bug" because gcc 4.4 never claimed to fully support `std::thread`, as such you can't really expect it to work.

**edit**: one thing that just came to my mind is, that sometimes linking statically to glibc and/or libpthread did not work in those old versions.